# How to map boolean with FluentNhibernate and SQLite

Tags: .net, database, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I understand I need to save boolean in SQLite as Integer, True/False as 1/0 I guess. But how is this done in the mapping file?

Do I need to write some custom mapping convention class?  I've never done this before, so would be very helpful if someone could offer an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map it like a any other property. Conversion happens under the covers. So if your entity has something like

```
public virtual bool IsArchived { get; set; }
```

the Map file for this property would have an entry like so

```
Map(x => x.IsArchived);
```

Comment: ah.. I see. I made some other mistake which made it seem like it didn't work, but sure it does. cheers!